# How to add electron to angular project made with angular/cli?

Tags: angular, electron, angular-cli

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

And I am trying to add electron to project made via angular/cli with its specific structure. However I get "unable to find electron app" when i try to run 'npm start'. Should I modify the main.ts from the src? Currently it looks like:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and it's standard one without modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just learning abut electron as well. The following setup worked for me:

Step 1)
create an electron-directory below the src-directory, which contains a package.json and a main.js (see https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/)

Step 2)
install electron globally:

```
npm install -g electron
```

Step 3)
update package.json (add 2 entries to the scripts-section):

```
...
"build-electron": "ng build --base-href . && copy src\\electron\\* dist",
"electron": "npm run build-electron && electron dist",
...
```

Step 4)
start the application:

```
npm run electron
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: thanks it worked. I use this script to make it work on osx.                     
       "build-electron": "ng build --base-href . && cp src/electron/* dist",

Comment: Shouldn't it be && cp -R src/electron/* dist

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json needs to be modified. Make sure to add the **"main": "main.js"**  to you package.json.

for eg:

```
{
  "name": "package-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  ...
}
```